# Cannot generate random number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, innerhtml

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Your Luck Here!</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) +1);
document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test Your Luck Here!</h1>
<p id="value1"></p>
<button onlick="myFunction()">Roll!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to generate any number between 1 and 6 using JavaScript but i haven't been very successful so far. I have tried giving it a variable and an `id` for my button but it doesn't seem to be functioning. I went on w3schools and they had something similar to this. Thanks.

Comment: 'onlick' will not work, onclick - should work. :)

Comment: dont google "onlick" event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nevermind mentioned that it should be `onclick` rather than `onlick` in one line of your code. These kind of syntax errors can happen frequently. Consider using the `Browser Debugging Tools` or `JSBin` whenever something doesn't seems to work. You can't post questions here just for SO to figure out your syntax errors. :-)

Working [demo](http://jsbin.com/tugowe/edit?html,output), after changing `onlick` to `onclick`.